# Move Toolbar Up with Toolbar

Tags: swift, keyboard, toolbar

I am working with a table view within a normal view controller. I have a toolbar with a textfield on the bottom of the screen. When I tap on the textField the keyboard appears and covers the textfield. How do I raise the textfield & toolbar to the height of the keyboard? Swift version 5...previous responses only for old versions of swift. I don't want to use COCOA PODS

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the **IQKeyboardManager** library for this.

You can install it with Cocoapods. Add required code to AppDelegate.

See this link for instructions.

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: I'd rather not use cocoa pods

Comment: Fair enough. What is your reasoning behind that?

Comment: using git repo w a team. Pods make it messy. do you have any swift code that could solve the issue? I have it the toolbar raising once, but after the keyboard hides the first time, the second time and after the toolbar stays hidden behind the keyboard.